# Asterisk unable to find master config file

Tags: asterisk

I have strange problem after I've installed Asterisk on my CentOS server. So, I have used tutorial [step-by-step](http://kb.cloudatcost.com/uncategorized/how-to-install-and-setup-asterisk-14-pbx-on-centos-7/) and didn't get any error or warnings. Whole installation went successfully.

When I try to log into Asterisk CLI with `asterisk -r` I've got this error

> [root@asterisk-14.6.1]# asterisk -r
>
> Unable to open specified master config file '/usr/local/etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf', using built-in defaults
>
> Unable to connect to remote asterisk (does /usr/local/var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl exist?)
>
> [root@asterisk-14.6.1]#

What does this means? I can't find anything about master config file. My asterisk.conf file is in `/etc/asterisk`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 asterisk asterisk  5332 18 sep 12,15 asterisk.conf
```

not in `'/usr/local/etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf'`

Asterisk is 100% running

```
[root@asterisk-14.6.1]# systemctl status asterisk
● asterisk.service - LSB: Asterisk PBX
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/asterisk; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since mon 2017-09-18 12:36:16 EEST; 3s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 33977 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/asterisk stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 34000 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/asterisk start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 34025 (asterisk)
   CGroup: /system.slice/asterisk.service
           ├─34023 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/safe_asterisk
           └─34025 /usr/sbin/asterisk -f -vvvg -c

sep 18 12:36:16  systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Asterisk PBX...
sep 18 12:36:16  asterisk[34000]: Starting asterisk:
sep 18 12:36:16  systemd[1]: PID file /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
sep 18 12:36:16  systemd[1]: asterisk.service: Supervising process 34025 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.
sep 18 12:36:16  systemd[1]: Started LSB: Asterisk PBX.
```

I have changed also this permissions to asterisk user

```
[root@asterisk-14.6.1]# ls -l /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl
  srwxr-xr-x 1 asterisk asterisk 0 18 sep 12,36
```

/var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl

I was able to log into CLI with `asterisk -vvvvc` and I can see few errors

> Unable to open specified master config file '/usr/local/etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf', using built-in defaults
>
> [Sep 18 12:40:24] ERROR[34584]: logger.c:1823 init_logger: Errors detected in logger.conf.  Default console logging is being used.
>
> [Sep 18 12:40:24] WARNING[34584]: loader.c:1293 load_modules: No 'modules.conf' found, no modules will be loaded.
>
> [Sep 18 12:40:24] WARNING[34584]: loader.c:1293 load_modules: No 'modules.conf' found, no modules will be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did install with /usr/local/ prefix.

Now you have  2 choices

1. reinstall, do configure with --prefix=/
2. or do symlink

   mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/

   ln -s /etc/asterisk /usr/local/etc/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Thats very strange because I didn't add any prefix at all. All I've done is `./configure –libdir=/usr/lib64`

Answer (score 0):

Running

`make samples` inside `/usr/src/asterisk-<your version>` resolved the issue for me